# What is the resolved node in an orderByChild query?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase documentation on [structuring the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data) mentions the following:

> ...when you fetch data at a location in your database, you also retrieve all of its child nodes.

I have the following basic data structure:

```
databaseRoot: {
    orders: {
        order1: {
            firebaseId: firebaseUid,
            ...
        }
    }
    orderItems: {
        order1: {
            firebaseId: firebaseUid,
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

In my android start-up code I intend to sync the orders and orderItems that belong to the current user to handle the offline scenario.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getReference("orders").orderByChild("firebaseId").equalTo(firebaseUser.uid).keepSynced(true)
FirebaseDatabase.getReference("orderItems").orderByChild("firebaseId").equalTo(firebaseUser.uid).keepSynced(true)
```

**My Question:**
Do the sync references consider the data location to be the entire Orders and OrderItems nodes, respectively?  Or does it resolve down to the specific child nodes that satisfy the firebase user id equal to the current user?

My hope is for the latter to be the result, as the client does not need any records beyond those belonging to the current user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `keepSynced(true)` on a location is essentially the same as keeping a listener with an empty callback on that location.

So these two commands will ensure you that the orders and orderItems for the specific user are in cache.

But if that is the type of behavior you want, you might want to consider keep the data in a simpler structure: `/orders/firebaseUid/order1`, `/orders/firebaseUid/order2`, etc. With this structure you won't need a query to get the orders for a user and can just read from (and call `keepSynced()` on) `/orders/firebaseUid`.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense! Re: your suggestion on data structure,  I considered that model but  I structured the data the way I did because orders can be transferred between users and due to the way data is received in firebase, I have to bulk update (set) the data in orders and order items.  So keying them by use id might create the new record for the new user while preserving the order for the old user.  Open to additional suggestions to handle that though.

Comment: Neh, if the ownership can be transferred my model makes less sense. You could potentially list the `orderKeysForUser` in a similar hierarchy, so `/orderKeysForUser/firebaseUid/order1` with a value of `true`. This is mentioned in the Firebase docs as an "index" and it also prevents needing a query (which sometimes end up being scalability limits over time).